# Image Processing: Finding contours of an image that reaches image boundaries

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, convex-hull

I am trying to calculate the roughness of lines in an image, and believe that cv2.convexHull and cv2.convexivityDefects are the way to go. The issue that I am running into is the lines cannot be collected into contours because they go outside the image boundaries. Below is the original image and the edges that I was able to form from it. Is there a way to just close off the shapes or make contours even though they are open? Or is there a better way to go about finding the roughness?

To clarify, these are the functions that I am trying to use currently. I am new to image processing so I have no idea what modules could help here.

```py
cnts = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints=True)
hullDefects = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints=False)
spiralDefects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hullDefects)
```

[image: Original Image]

[image: Edges plot]

Comment: Edit a black or background color border into the image?

Comment: Is there a function that simply adds a border to an image?

Comment: You could add it manually in paint just to try it out. Otherwise use opencv drawing functions.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, with some searching I found a function ImageOps.expand(img,border=20,fill='black') that was able add a border easily. Thanks!